# how to give power and ETH to pi pico W at same time?

Tags: pi-pico, ethernet-port, rfid, usb-hub

Learning following project https://github.com/sbcshop/Raspberry-Pi-Pico-RFID-Expansion.

Now the requirement is to connect project with Ethernet network, also provide power supply at same time.

Qustion:

1. can we fulfil above requirement using this hat (https://thepihut.com/products/ethernet-and-usb-hub-hat-for-raspberry-pi) ?
2. or using this product (https://thepihut.com/products/ethernet-hub-and-usb-hub-w-micro-usb-otg-connector) ?
3. or is it any other efficient/cheaper way ?

**So, with 2nd product the idea is to connect Pi Pico with Hub and connect power USB and ETH  cable with it, with expectation to get power + Ethernet.**

Comment: what does `provide power supply` mean?

Comment: hi @jsotola Simply to provide power to Pi Pico, either connect to pc or to something like this https://thepihut.com/products/raspberry-pi-zero-uk-power-supply